# Deleting each final value in multidimensional hash (perl)

Tags: perl, hash, perl-data-structures

I have a multidimensional hash (the number of dimensions will vary) where every value is either a simple scalar value or a reference to another hash.

Is there a good way to delete each final value, preserving the elements which point to other hashes? Basically, take all the meat off the skeleton.

Comment: It would help a lot if you showed a sample of your hash and the result you want. When you say *"delete each final value"*, do you want to remove the hash element altogether, including the key, or do you just want to set the value to `undef`?

Comment: $VAR1 = {
          'Peti Bar' => {
                          'Mathematics' => 82,
                          'Art' => 99,
                          'Literature' => 88
                        },
          'Foo Bar' => {
                         'Mathematics' => 97,
                         'Literature' => 67
                       }
        };

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect there are good modules out there that could help with the problem, probably several, but I always have a hard time choosing one when it comes to traversing data structures in Perl, and the problem isn't super complex to begin with. So here it is done "by hand":

```
sub prune {
  my ($href) = @_;
  while (my ($key, $value) = each %$href) {
    if (ref $value eq 'HASH') {
      prune($value);
    } else {
      delete $href->{$key};
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to write your own recursive function. Something like this (which I have not tested):

```
sub cleanHash($)
{
    my $hash = $_[0];
    foreach my $k ( keys( %$hash ) )
    {
        if( ref( $hash->{$k} ) eq 'HASH' )
        {
            cleanHash( $hash->{$k} );
        }
        else
        {
            delete( $hash->{$k} );
        }
    }
} # END cleanHash

my %h;
....
cleanHash( \%h );
```

Comment: You should *never* use prototypes for your Perl subroutines. They are different from most languages' prototypes and probably don't do what you want. It's also preferable to use `snake_case` for local identifiers. Capital letters are reserved for globals such as package names.